# archive-{custom_post_type}.php not getting recognized wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

I have registered a custom post type `city` with 2 taxonomies `city_categories` and `cities`. But wordpress is taking archive.php instead of archive-city.php, don't understand where am I mistaking. It works only if I create a taxonomy-cities.php and then is taking taxonomies-cities.php. How can I make it take directly archive-city.php

```
register_post_type( 'city',
    array(
        'labels' => 
            array(
            'name' => 'City Guides',
            'singular_name' => 'City Guides',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New retailer',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit retailer',
            'new_item' => 'New retailer',
            'view' => 'View',
            'view_item' => 'View retailer',
            'search_items' => 'Search retailers',
            'not_found' => 'No retailer found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Shop retailer in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent retailer'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('city_categories'),
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'travel')
    )
);  

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels, // defined correctly, shortened the code
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'city_categories', array('city'), $args );

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels, // defined correctly, shortened the code
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'sort' => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'cities', array('city'), $args );
```

Comment: Why have you named the taxonomy exactly like the post type?

Comment: @kaiser Where is that, they are different. Taxonomies are city_categories and cities, and post type is city.

Comment: Verify that template is named precisely what you think it's named and resides in directory you think it's residing. :) Any other code (plugins/etc) running that might be interfering?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the permalinks?

Comment: @TomásCot How to do that?

Comment: Just visit "Settings >> Permalinks" and click Save Changes

Comment: Please read your question again. In the first sentence you are saying both the post type and the taxonomy are called `cities`. If not, then please file an [edit] and fix that.

Comment: @kaiser My bad fixed.

Comment: If *any* of the answers has been helpful consider accepting one - if you need more information read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it works perfectly if you register the post type in the `init` action hook. In your code I don't see the action hook where you register the post type. Cna you try this? (remember to flush rewirte rules after update the code. Note that I remove the undefined variable `$labels` in the `$args` array for taxonomies):

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_register_post_type_and_taxonomies');
function cyb_register_post_type_and_taxonomies() {
    register_post_type( 'city',
                        array(
                            'labels' => 
                                array(
                                    'name' => 'City Guides',
                                    'singular_name' => 'City Guides',
                                    'add_new' => 'Add New',
                                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New retailer',
                                    'edit' => 'Edit',
                                    'edit_item' => 'Edit retailer',
                                    'new_item' => 'New retailer',
                                    'view' => 'View',
                                    'view_item' => 'View retailer',
                                    'search_items' => 'Search retailers',
                                    'not_found' => 'No retailer found',
                                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Shop retailer in Trash',
                                    'parent' => 'Parent retailer'
                                ),
                            'public' => true,
                            'menu_position' => 6,
                            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
                            'has_archive' => true,
                            'taxonomies' => array('city_categories'),
                            'can_export' => true,
                            'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'travel')
                         )
    );
    $args = array( 
            'labels' => array(),
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'query_var' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'city_categories', array('city'), $args );

    $args = array(
            'labels' => array(), // defined correctly, shortened the code
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'sort' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'cities', array('city'), $args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Still sounds something went wrong with your rewrite rules, try adding [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) at the end of your function that contains the registrations calls you posted in your questions. Like this:

```
flush_rewrite_rules( false );
```

Setting the parameter `$hard` to `false` means you won't update the `.htaccess` and just do a update of the `rewrite_rules` transient. Should be enough though.

**But** do not forget to remove this line from your code after testing, because otherwise it will be executed every time your site is called, which is bad and you certainly don't want that.